# Error when adding button to activity

Tags: java, android, xml

When I try to add b5 button it shows my an error. b5 button is a normal Button and b1&b2 are image buttons. Is there any problem to use both imagebuttons & normal button in same file?

**My Activity:**

```
public class Settings extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    ImageButton b1, b2;
    Button b5;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);

        b5=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_ok);
        b1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        b2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);

        b5.setOnClickListener(this);
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
        b2.setOnClickListener(this);

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (SoundFlag.music_flag == 1) {    
            b1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_av_volume_up);
        }
        else{           
            b1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_av_volume_off);
        }

        if (SoundFlag.sound_flag == 1) {
            b2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_av_volume_up);
        }
        else{

            b2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_av_volume_off);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        SoundFlag values= new SoundFlag();

        if (v == b1) {
            if (values.music_flag == 1){            
                values.music_flag=0;        
                b1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_av_volume_off);
            }
            else
            {
                values.music_flag=1;
                b1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_av_volume_up);
            }  
        }

        else if (v == b2) {             
            if (values.sound_flag== 1) {
                values.sound_flag=0;
                b2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_av_volume_off);
            }
            else
            {
                values.sound_flag=1;
                b2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_av_volume_up);
            }           
        }

     else if (v==b5){           
            //finish();
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Add the stacktrace from your logcat

Comment: can you please share xml file ?

Comment: No!! there is no problem in using any types of buttons  in same activity.

Comment: Can you post your errors here? Show me how  you setting onclick Listener to all types of  Button  here?

Comment: at least the corresponding xml file would be nice and when you get the error. is it the ``findViewById`` call or the ``setOnClickListener``?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Button with id `R.id.button_ok` in your `R.layout.settings`.